# xslt working with keys and variables

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, marc

Hi all this question is related to this: [xsl get element values from another node tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434654/xsl-get-element-values-from-another-node-tree) But this time I have a working xslt.

I am currently working on the following xml:

```
 <record>
  <leader>01877nz  a2200433o  4500</leader>
  <controlfield tag="001">1</controlfield>
        ... (more controlfields tag 002 to 010)
  <datafield tag="013" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
   <subfield code="a">formerge</subfield>
  </datafield>
          ... (more datafield tags, datafield tags are from 011 to 999)
  <datafield tag="150" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
   <subfield code="a">Borneo</subfield>
  </datafield>
          ... (more datafield tags, datafield tags are from 011 to 999)
  <datafield tag="550" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
   <subfield code="w">g</subfield>
   <subfield code="a">South East Asia</subfield>
   <subfield code="c">c_7260</subfield>
  </datafield>
       ... (more datafield tags, datafield tags are from 011 to 999)
  </record>

       ... (more records)

  <record>
       ... (more records fields)
       ... (more records fields)
  </record>

  <record>
   <leader>02462nz  a2200553o  4500</leader>
   <controlfield tag="001">2</controlfield>
         ... (more controlfields tag 002 to 010)
   <datafield tag="013" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="a">formerge</subfield>
   </datafield>
   <datafield tag="035" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="a">c_7260</subfield>
   </datafield>
       ... (more datafield tags, datafield tags are from 011 to 999)
   <datafield tag="151" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="a">South East Asia</subfield>
   </datafield>
       ... (more datafield tags, datafield tags are from 011 to 999)
  </record>
```

I have the following xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="marc">
 <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="term" match="//datafield[@tag='151'][subfield[@code='a']]" use="." />

 <xsl:template match="//datafield[@tag='151'][subfield[@code='a']]">
  <xsl:variable name="t550a" select="//datafield[@tag='550'][subfield[@code='a']]" />
  <xsl:for-each select="key('term','$550a')">
   <xsl:value-of select="//controlfield[@tag='001']" />
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this, I created an index of all 151 through keys (term). I also created a variable 't550a'. Through the keys function, I match the 550a tags (datafield tag="550" subfield code="a") with term key. And then get the value of controlfield tag 001 of that key. I also wanted to get all the nodes of my xml thus the "xsl:copy". With the xslt I have, it seems that datafield tag 151 is being removed.

I wanted to get in 550 field the following:

```
        ... (other fields omitted)
<datafield tag="550" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
 <subfield code="w">g</subfield>
 <subfield code="a">South East Asia</subfield>
 <subfield code="c">c_7260</subfield>
 <subfield code="0">2</subfield>
</datafield>
          ... (other fields omitted)

<datafield tag="550" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
 <subfield code="w">h</subfield>
 <subfield code="a">Borneo</subfield>
 <subfield code="c">c_1017</subfield>
 <subfield code="0">1</subfield>
</datafield>
```

So 550 subfield a South East Asia will have additional subfield 0 with value 2, which is based from the controlfield 001 of 151 subfield a South East Asia. And also 550 subfield a Borneo will have additional subfield 0 with value 1, which is based from the controlfield 001 of 151 subfield a Borneo.

Can somebody lead me to doing this correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have your template matching the wrong element. If you are looking to add a child node onto the "550" field, you should have a template matching that

```
<xsl:template match="datafield[@tag='550'][subfield[@code='a']]">
```

I would also slightly adjust the key to this, because at the moment the key would be using the whitespace nodes too (although this may be removed if you were using `xsl:strip-space`

```
 <xsl:key name="term" match="datafield[@tag='151']" use="subfield[@code='a']" />
```

The next problem you have is with your definition of the `tt50a` variable. You really want to be using a relative expression here, because at the moment it will pick up the first matching element anywhere in the document. You should do this instead (which works because you are now positioned on the `550` node)

```
<xsl:variable name="t550a" select="subfield[@code='a']" />
```

However, it appears you are not actually using this variable. You current use of the key, `key('term','$550a')`, is using a string literal, not the variable. You probably mean to do this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('term',$t550a)">
```

And finally, within the `xsl:for-each` where you doing `//controlfield[@tag='001']` then this selects the first `controlfield` in the document. I think you only want to select the one in the current `record`. As `record` is a parent of the current `datafield`, you can just do this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../controlfield[@tag='001']" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="rdf dc marc">
 <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="term" match="datafield[@tag='151']" use="subfield[@code='a']" />

 <xsl:template match="datafield[@tag='550'][subfield[@code='a']]">
   <xsl:variable name="t550a" select="subfield[@code='a']" />
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     <xsl:for-each select="key('term',$t550a)">
       <subfield code="0">
         <xsl:value-of select="../controlfield[@tag='001']" />
       </subfield>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This won't give the output you show in your question exactly, because your input XML only has one `550` node.

Comment: Wow! This is nice Tim C., it saved me time trying to figure out my crosswalk. I was correct with keys and variable, but I don't know yet how to execute it correctly. And thanks also Abel. :)

Answer (score 1):

> With the xslt I have, it seems that datafield tag 151 is being removed.

Yes, that is correct, because that is what you have instructed it to do:

```
 <xsl:template match="//datafield[@tag='151'][subfield[@code='a']]">
  <xsl:variable name="t550a" select="//datafield[@tag='550'][subfield[@code='a']]" />
  <xsl:for-each select="key('term','$550a')">
   <xsl:value-of select="//controlfield[@tag='001']" />
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
```

This means that: when the `datafield` is matched, go over all terms with value `$550a` and select (from the root!) on each iteration, all controlfield values. I assume you would rather have the controlfields from the current node, like `.//controlfield....`?

But you are not creating any element here. If you want that, you should probably add that. I.e.:

```
 <xsl:template match="//datafield[@tag='151'][subfield[@code='a']]">
  <xsl:variable name="t550a" select="//datafield[@tag='550'][subfield[@code='a']]" />
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('term','$550a')">
      <xsl:value-of select="//controlfield[@tag='001']" />
    </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

which will copy the `datafield`.

Comment: Thanks Abel! I tried your corrected template but it seems I still get the same. I added after the copy of all nodes:       <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: @schnydszch If you added the whole matching template, you should receive an error. I just meant updating the existing template with the code above.

Comment: I assume you would rather have the controlfields from the current node, like .//controlfield.... I want to get the controlfield 001 from the keys matching from the values of 550. So 550 subfield a South East Asia will have additional subfield 0 with value 2, which is based from the controlfield 001 of 151 subfield a South East Asia. And also 550 subfield a Borneo will have additional subfield 0 with value 1, which is based from the controlfield 001 of 151 subfield a Borneo.